# The provided key element does not match the schema error as soon as there is a primary key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I use aws amplify and have a graphql schema like this i push with amplify push:

```
type User @model  {
  id: ID!
  lastname: String!
  customerID: ID!
  status: Status @connection
  statusID: ID!
}

type Status @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}
```

I can insert a new user in the appsync console without error with:

```
mutation CreateUser($input: CreateUserInput!) {
  createUser(input: $input) {
    id
    customerID
    lastname
    status {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

{"input": {
  "id": 1,
"customerID": 1,
  "statusID": 1
"lastname": "Doe"
}
}
```

But as soon as i create the same dynamodb table user with the primary key customerID by adding @key(fields: ["customerID"]) in the graphql schema i get the following error in the appsync console:

```
 {
      "path": [
        "createUser",
        "status"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 5,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 4SUT0SN1R6BKS8KG2V1AGUCHGRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
    }
```

The user is created correctly though in the db.
I don´t see any difference between the 2 tables in the created code besides the pk customerID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your schema models a "has-one" relationship, you can refer to this document for sample schemas
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#has-one

The @connection directive without arguments will use the primary key. The Amplify CLI will also generate the following input type for you.
If I understand your intention correctly, the statusID field in the User type is not needed in your schema.
You can specify the `fields` argument in the @connection definition if you want to use a specific field (e.g. "statusID") for the connection, there's an example in the document too.

When you execute the creation mutations, you should create the Status object first, get its Id, and then create the User object and specify the userStatusId to be the Status Id.

```
input CreateUserInput {
  id: ID
  lastname: String!
  customerID: ID!
  statusID: ID!
  userStatusId: ID
}
```